# MINIFS using OR function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, nested-if

I’m trying to find the minimum date in column B if any cell in columns E, F, or G contains the word `banana`.

Give the minimum date in column B
IF: column E contains “banana”
OR IF: column F contains “banana”
OR IF: column G contains “banana”

I’m not quite sure how to nest these statements or if an array formula is needed. I tried a variety of nested `MAX(IF(OR` formulas but kept getting a parse error. Also tried an array but also got a parse error. Appreciate help trying to understand how to get this formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also

```
=min(filter(B:B,(D:D="Banana")+(E:E="Banana")+(F:F="Banana")))
```

(you can only get an AND condition out of MINIFS - see [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/42428/filtercondition-or-condition-syntax) for how to get an OR condition generally)

Here is a version that finds "Banana split" etc.

```
=min(filter(B:B,isnumber(search("Banana",D:D))
               +isnumber(search("Banana",E:E))
               +isnumber(search("Banana",F:F))))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I just spent a couple hours trying to figure this out when I should've just used your formula. Many, many thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! I thought Dmin was also a good idea, but I couldn't get it to work with empty cells.

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like:

**`=MINIFS(B1:B, E1:E, "banana")`**
**`=MINIFS(B1:B, F1:F, "banana")`**
**`=MINIFS(B1:B, G1:G, "banana")`**

and then:

**`=MIN(I1:K1)`**

**[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IWQWDK9piw_xFVm_48XZ8YAS_LQqXi6sd2GITLIfoAQ/edit#gid=2143514292)**

[image]

Comment: thanks for doing this! i liked your nested formula. however, i don't think MINIFS allows for the **contains** condition. when i updated your formula to look for `"*banana*"` it came up with an error. Here's the modified formula I used `=min(filter(B3:B,(G3:G="*banana*")+(E3:E="*banana*")+(F3:F="*banana*")))` (see test doc). is there a way to get it to look for min values in B when either columns E, F, or G contain banana? (not the exact word "banana" but "banana peel," "banana split", "banana tree", etc)

Comment: your first solution creates 4 new cells; 3 individual cells contain their own `MINIFS` formula. then you find the `MINIFS` between those 3. that works even with `"*banana*"` but for some reason, the nested version does not allow the **contains** qualifier ( * ). am i doing something wrong? is it possible to use your nested formula with the wildcards/*?

Comment: I think you are referring to my answer with the filter, I will edit a 'contains' version into it

Comment: what about using `DMIN`? that allows for wildcards. i've never used it but will try something out